# How can I prevent downloads going to iCloud?

Tags: ios, ipad

On an iPad, files downloaded with Safari end up in iCloud by default. How can I make the default be the local storage instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Settings > Safari > Downloads you can change the folder that is used to store your downloads.

It defaults to iCloud Drive but can be adjusted to any location, including in the "On My iPhone" section which won't sync anywhere

Comment: This will prevent the synching of the downloaded files to iCloud but not them being included in a backup of the iPhone to iCloud if the iCloud Backup is turned on and the folder selected for Safari downloads is somehow not excluded from the backup.

Comment: Good callout, however I think most people expect backups to include all files downloaded on their device